# How to show Image in Android without ImageView?

Tags: android, image-processing, imageview

I am a newbie in android programming. Now, I'm currently developing an android application. My application will show an image, but I don't want to use ImageView. Can anyone help me? or can anyone tell me other ways to show the image?? thank you....

Comment: There are a lot of ways to display an image in Android. But first thing is, why don't you use ImageView?

Comment: i'm to try experiment to show image other than image view. do you any ways to display image??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use any of the view to show image..
for ex,.

Relativelayout,linearlayout,button,TextView..etc.

you can set **android:backgroud="@drawable/ur_img"**

if any query then tell me.
I hope its useful to you...

Comment: yes, but it does not limit to these. You can also use 3rd party libraries to "draw" the images, e.g. Cocos2d-android, OpenGL, etc

Comment: oke thanks dipali for your answer, this can succesfully run...

Comment: Thanks Raptor, i'll try do that....